# DLL: Can I use __declspec(dllexport) when SDK header file doesn't use it

Tags: c++, dllexport

I'm working with a SDK which expects my DLL to export some functions. The SDK provides a header file like this of the functions to export:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    HRESULT extern WINAPI Foobar();

#pragma pack(pop)

#ifdef __cplusplus
}    /*extern "C"*/
#endif
```

https://github.com/sergiofst/wosa-xfs-spi-base-framework/blob/master/depends/INCLUDE/XFSSPI.H

My problem is, I didn't find out how I can use this header on the provider (dllexport) side, since everytime I try to add `__declspec(dllexport)`:

```
__declspec(dllexport) HRESULT WINAPI Foobar() {
...
}
```

I get `error C2375: 'Foobar': redefinition; different linkage`.

So is there a way how I can use the header file provided by the SDK or am I forced to use a def file or copy/edit function definitions?

Best regards.

Comment: It is technically possible.  You need to create a .def file that tells the linker, "I didn't actually implement this function, it lives over there".  [This blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121116-00/?p=6073) talks about it, but it is actually about a complication doing this.  It tends to be easier to just export a Baz() function whose function body isn't anything more then `return Foobar();`, avoids the joy of maintaining .def files.

Comment: @Hans Passant:  That won't work. He's implementing the dll and the other guy is calling it by that name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you could try adding /EXPORT:Foobar to your link.exe command line.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/export-exports-a-function for details.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest, stupidest, obvious method is to copy the header file into your project and add dllexport to it.

The next method is to not include the header file in the file implementing that method.

Then there's the .def file for which I want somebody else to answer.

Comment: I know that this is working, but I don't like the idea of copying a header which already contains all information. And I'm aware that a .def file would work as well.